# image enlarge using UL and LI not working

Tags: html, css

Using the following code for a simple image enlarge (to show QR code image when user hovers the icon )

Weird thing is im using the same code on 2 designs, and on one it is not working?

Please look at the bottom of the pages, on the footers for the WeChat icon next to social icons.

Working on https://www.webxury.com/datacenter/

Not working on
http://webxury.net/design/index.php

CSS

```
ul.enlarge{
list-style-type:none; /*remove the bullet point*/
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: right;
}
ul.enlarge li{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul.enlarge img{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
}
ul.enlarge span img{
opacity: 1 !important;
}
ul.enlarge span{
position:absolute;
top: -9999px;
}
ul.enlarge li:hover span{ 
top: -110px; /*the distance from the bottom of the thumbnail to the top of     the popup image*/
left: 0px; /*distance from the left of the thumbnail to the left of the     popup image*/
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="enlarge"><li><img src="images/wc.png" width="32px" height="32px"   alt="#" /><span><img src="images/qrcode.png" alt="QR" /></span></li></ul>
```

Comment: Check your error console. There are multiple errors with JS and loading of JS files that may have something to do with it.

Comment: Sorry but how can I do that? Lol

Comment: In Chrome, F12 for Developer Tools, and the Console tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked at your sites and found why. It actually shows but in a wrong position - so you dont see it. 
It works in the first site because .col-md-4 container inside footer (where the icons are located) are relative-positioned). Bu there is no relative parent in the second site.

When you set that image icon wrapper span as absolute-poisoned, it goes out of screen because it takes the closest relative-positioned parent which is the body as its benchmark.

To fix it, please set position relative to either .ul.enlarge or #footer so that absolute position can limit the area within. (you will need to adjust position values a bit although). I just tested it works in this way. 
Or alternatively create another relative positioned parent for that area.